# Why my JMETER case output not as strictly as I have defined?

Tags: jmeter, fifo

I have a jmeter project that is of 1 thread, loop of X rounds. The initial **queue_username** value is set as: "**token-user**" in the **jp@gc - Inter-Thread Communication PostProcessor** area.

In each running session, I would like it to pop up the **queue_username** value from the  **jp@gc - Inter-Thread Communication PostProcessor** section, and also it would put a different value for the **queue_username** field, as you can see in my code.

[image]

So ideally, during the running, I would like to have the output as if:

```
name is token-user
name is token2-user 
name is token-user
name is token2-user
name is token-user
name is token2-user 
name is token-user
name is token2-user
...
```

But in reality, here is what I have received:

```
name is token-user
name is token-user
name is token2-user
name is token2-user
name is token-user
name is token-user
name is token2-user
name is token2-user
...
```

Why it is not of the sequential order as I have defined. Any comments?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be sequential, maybe you have queue which is not empty and it returns values from previous executions.

As per [documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/#Note-on-Clearing-Queues):

> **Note on Clearing Queues**
>
> **For Plugins**
>
> PreProcessor and PostProcessor clear queues at test start and test stop.
>
> **For Functions**
> When you stop JMeter test, queues are not cleared automatically (if you haven't used Pre/PostProcessors), so when starting new test you may have some values from previous run in FIFOs. Queues are cleared with the first fifoPut call. To fight this issue you may choose queue names that changes with every test run (eg. relying on test start time, etc).

So double check the size of your queue via `__fifoSize()` function and either clear the queue or rename it to something dynamic and you will get sequential usernames.

[image]

More information: [Inter-Thread Communication](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#comm)

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I was running your case in my JMETER ENV, I have seen  the buffer is keeping steady-growing, I guess each pop() call does not necessarily remove the item in the queue So, I have added  an explicitly clear() call after the pop(). Thanks for the tips.